# Load elf gdb error

Tags: eclipse, windows, binary, gdb, elf

I am trying to load an elf file into some .gdb file.\
When running the gdb file from cmd (Windows 7 - 64b), everything seems to be ok.
The commands execute properly, and the elf is loaded into the SRAM of my board.
The problem is when the same gdb file is ran from Eclipse (the Automotive feature of Eclipse).
The error I get:
Error in sourced command file:
"binary.elf" is not an object file: File format not recognized.
Can you help me to figure out what the problem should be?

Comment: More detailed explanation is required. Loading elf into .gdb probably means you load it from gdb script? Eclipse supports different launch configuration types. Are you using right kind of launch for your board? This sound like maybe you are not.

Answer (score 1):

> `"binary.elf" is not an object file: File format not recognized`

This error means that you've tried to do (an equivalent of) `file binary.elf` in a GDB that was not compiled with ELF support (i.e. into *native* Windows version of GDB). That obviously wouldn't work.

You need to set up Eclipse to use appropriate *cross*-GDB, i.e. GDB that runs on Windows but knows how to debug ELF files. As dbrank0 said, you need to use correct launch configuration in Eclipse.